# Finding the maximum and minimum value out of a list from a dictonary - Interview Question

Tags: python

Given below is the stock data set which shows stock and its predicted price over the next 7 working days/sessions an end-user I want to know what should be my buy price and what should be my sell price for each share so that I can earn maximum profit.

E.g. For RIL, if I buy it in the first session and sell it in the 4th session I will get 200 profit.

Also, what would you do if the maximum price is on the 1st day itself?

Test Case:

```
Input:
StockId,PredictedPricr
RIL,[1000,1005,1090,1200,1000,900,890]
HDFC,[890,940,810,730,735,960,980]
INFY,[1001,902,1000,990,1230,1100,1200]

Output:
StockId|BuyPrice|SellPrice|Profit
RIL|1000|1200|200
HDFC|730|980|250
INFY|902|1230|328
```

You can use any language of your choice, I preferably would use python dictionaries for this.

Comment: I removed the sql tag.  You explicitly asked for a python solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I remembered that there is a [leetcode question](https://leetcode.com/problems/best-time-to-buy-and-sell-stock/) that asks almost exactly your problem. For different solutions and explanations, you can look at the discussion section of the question. The difference is that there you only have to solve the problem for one stock. Here is the solution I used back when I solved it:

```
def max_profit(prices):
    p1 = 0
    max_profit = -1
    current_buy = -1
    current_sell = -1

    for p2 in range(1, len(prices)):

        if prices[p2] < prices[p1]:
            p1=p2
        elif prices[p2] - prices[p1] > max_profit:
            current_buy = prices[p1]
            current_sell = prices[p2]
            max_profit = current_sell - current_buy
            

    return (current_buy, current_sell, max_profit)
```

The input is simply the `array` of prices that you have for one of the stocks. What you have to do is loop over your stocks and call the method for each of them.

Now, how does the code work? We iterate over the array and try to find the sequence where we have the highest profit. We simply have a start index (`p1`), where our sequence begins and increase the end pointer (`p2`). The endpointer is increased to find the highest profit with our start index. If we find a lower price than our start index (via the end pointer) we move the start index to this lower price and simply continue to increase the end pointer. So, the start pointer always points to the lowest prices that we currently know.

**Edit:** How to apply it on all stocks? As I said we simply have to iterate over the stocks and use the function on each one. How it is handled exactly depends on your input/output format. I assumed you use a dictionary:

```py
input_values = {
    'RIL':[1000,1005,1090,1200,1000,900,890],
    'HDFC':[890,940,810,730,735,960,980],
    'INFY':[1001,902,1000,990,1230,1100,1200],
}

result = []
for k, v in input_values.items():
    buy, sell, profit = max_profit(v)
    result.append([k, buy, sell, profit])
    
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[
    ['RIL', 1000, 1200, 200], 
    ['HDFC', 730, 980, 250], 
    ['INFY', 902, 1230, 328]
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your time to reply but, am already aware about the solution you provided only the issue is how to solve it for each stock

Comment: No problem. Just noticed that I gave you a Java solution. I changed it to a Python solution and added the buy and sell price you need. Also I showed how you can use it on all your stocks. The question is what do you need as input/output format? Is your input simply a string that has to be parsed? Also, why did you tag the question with `sql`?

Comment: Can you help me with how this line is working `buy, sell, profit = max_profit(v)
` 

Am trying to run this and it isn't running probably sue to this.

Comment: Coz I think you have provided me with two solutions and mixed the variables.

Comment: Did you use the updated function? The input I used is a `dict` with the stock id as `key` and the array of prices as `value`. In the loop `v` gets the array of prices for each stock assigned which is the input of the function. The function then returns a `tuple` of three values, which are assigned to the vars `buy`, `sell` and `profit`.

Comment: Got it @JANO, thanks a ton!

Comment: You're welcome! If it solved your question, you could accept the answer.